# How to return a stream from an MVC view?

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream, streamwriter

I'm fairly close I believe but my stream is either null or its been disposed.  Here is the sample code.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
{
   using (var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
   {
    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, null);
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, tw);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
    }
}
```

the calling code results in an objectDisposedException because the stream is disposed.  If I move the return outside of the using, the result is null. What am I doing wrong here?  Any ideas how I can this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a class in a `using` block, that class must implement `IDisposable`. When the block ends, it invokes `IDisposable.Dispose()` which disposes your Stream. This is a good practice, but if you want the stream, either remove the `using` or put the return inside it. I would go with the second option.

Comment: In the above code, the return is inside the using which does not work in this case.

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct. The above code should return a valid `MemoryStream` object. Can you post where you are calling the stream, i.e. the call statement to this method?

Comment: var stream = Utils.RenderViewToStream(this, "print", ViewData);

Comment: Can you check what if the properties `ms.CanSeek`, `ms.CanRead` are `true` before you return the stream? Also put the return outside the using blocks and check after they complete.

Comment: it appears that you may need to see more code because var stream is nowhere to be seen and if he's passing ViewData.. it looks like he is overriding that in the second line of code when creating new prehaps he should pass the ViewData by ref.. I could be wrong but I can't test his scenario..GRRR....

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski I does not matter, the `finally` (end of `using`) will always run before the return statement.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski: He is using a memory stream. It's always seekable, and readable.

Answer (score 2):

The using statement on the `StreamWriter` will also close the underlying stream.
Remove the `using` statement on the `StreamWriter` to keep the stream alive.
Another option would be to return a byte array rather than a memory stream.

```
return ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: The stream `ms` isn't attached to a using block; why would closing the streamwriter or htmltextwriter affect the state of the memory stream?

Comment: @DavidLively Well, that's how the `StreamWriter` works. Why that is you're gonna have to ask MS.

Comment: +1 a) Correct about the stream writer. b) There is really no point to return a stream since nothing is really streamed. Using `GetBuffer()` is a bit more efficient though

Comment: @Magnus I believe you - it's just surprising.

Comment: @jgauffin True, but note that `GetBuffer()` contains allocated bytes which might be unused.

Comment: @DavidLively I agree, I which they would add a `leaveOpen` parameter to the constructor of the `StreamWriter` like they have done with the [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ck2z1y.aspx)

Comment: @Magnus: Yep. The memory stream would be quite inefficient if it did not allocate a chunk each time it grows. (just an explanation if someone wonders why the buffer is larger)

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 usings he is saying put the return inside of the outter using()

like this

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
{
   using (var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
   {
    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, null);
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, tw);
    ms.Position = 0;
    }
  return ms;
}
```